# Do Lithuanians need a visa to visit the United States?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, visa-free-entry, lithuanian-citizens

I'm Lithuanian, 16 years old, and travelling for the first time. I want to visit the United States. Here's what I'm trying to understand:

- Do I need my parents' consent to book flight tickets and to fly?
- Do I need to apply for a US visa, or do I get a visa on arrival in the US?

Comment: For the US, you always almost need to secure authorisation before traveling. In your case, you need something called an ESTA. But are you still interested in the age angle? If so please add all these details to your question so that someone can post a proper answer.

Comment: Clearly you seem quite confused about the very fundamentals of the whole process. You may need someone who can explain to you in spoken language, not via written language.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie on the other hand, some people can make sense more easily of written explanations than they can of spoken ones.

Comment: @Crazydre Uh? I meant either a visa or an ESTA. You should read a little more carefully before lecturing others…

Comment: Getting to the US and back from Lithuania is most of two full days of travelling. Only spending a couple of days there seems like a very low return on that investment of travelling time.

Answer (score 10):

As a Lithuanian citizen you are able to enter the US without a visa, however you WILL require an approved [**ESTA**](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) (online passport Registration for USD 14 - don't get it from any site other than the linked one) before you travel - searching this site will find you several other questions that cover what is required for an ESTA.

However your biggest problem will be your age.  As you are below 18, you will require your parents consent to travel internationally from and to Lithuania -
 See [this website for full details](https://renkuosilietuva.lt/eng/pradzia/other-issues/child-care-after-parents-have-left-for-foreign-countries-and-minors-travelling/childrens-travelling-without-parents/).  You will also potentially need similar proof to enter the US.

However once you arrive, you will need somewhere to stay.  Hotels in the US will NOT allow someone below 18 to stay without an adult, so you will likely not be able to find somewhere to stay.

You will also need to consider things like medical insurance, as well as carrying a medical power of attorney in order to give someone the right to decide on any medical treatment that should be needed should you fall sick/have an accident whilst in the US (as you are under 18, you can legally not make these decisions for yourself)

In short, travelling to the US at this stage is likely not a good idea at all - especially given that you appear to have done very little research into what is required.

Comment: Parental authorisation is **not** required to enter the US, only highyl recommended.

Comment: It will definitely help me pass some immigration stops.

Comment: Hotel is solvable: parents sign for taking responsibility any damage their minor child causes and supply a credit card to the hotel, all this ahead of the time.

Comment: To clarify: do **all** Schengen countries require a minor to hold parental authorisation to exit? I know France does, and you said Lithuania does. But most likely OP won't exit Schengen in Lithuania, but in Latvia or elsewhere.

Comment: 1. You can skip the ESTA by coming in overland of you want. 2. I believe some hostels do take 16 year olds.

Comment: @chx Whislt technically that might be possible, I suspect you'll have a lot of trouble finding a hotel to do it - especially for a foreign resident/credit card.

Comment: The issue is not of damage, the issue is of liability as the person is legally a minor and is not able to enter into contracts (such as those required when renting a room).